# A question about an infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $\{ a_n \}, \{ b_n \}$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers. Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n $ converges(let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = C)$ and assume that $$  a_n \le a_1 \;(\forall n \in \mathbb N).$$  Then can I conclude that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n \leq a_1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n = a_1 C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as long as all your numbers are nonnegative, there is no problem with this reasoning.

You can write $$\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n\leq\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_1b_n\leq a_1\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty b_n=a_1 C$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For any finite $N$ we have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n b_n \leq a_1 \sum_{n=1}^N b_n \leq a_1 C$$

So we can let $N\to\infty$ and we're done.